# Why is the following code giving an error-"Error: 'NoneType' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was trying to implement decorators in python but got an error at the line 14 i.e  `hello()`

```py
    #The code-
    def maint(item1):
        def greet():
            print("Good Morning") 
            item1()
            print("Tanish")
        return greet()

    #decorator----
    @maint 
    def hello():
        print("Hello")
    # hello=maint(hello)
    hello()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `return greet()` should be `return greet`? Otherwise in your commented out example (and the same for the decorator) `hello=maint(hello)`, `maint` is returning the output from `greet` which is `None`, so you replace your function `hello` with `None` which is not a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return greet()
```

In the decorator, you call `greet()` and **return its result**. Since `greet()` has no explicit return, the result is `None`. It will help to realize that a decorator is shorthand syntax for something like this:

```
def hello():
   pass

hello = maint(hello)
```

Notice how hello gets reassigned to whatever `maint()` returns. In your case, `hello` is reassigned to `None`. So the call `hello()` causes the error.

To fix this, just `return greet` without the parentheses. Decorators always return a function. They should not call that function.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @TanishSarmah Please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it if you found it helpful.